How to set image half outside from top and bottom in flutter
I'm trying to create this design

but the image is not exactly where it should to be.
here is my code
Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: width * 0.9,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          gradient: const LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              AppColors.orangeColorLight,
              AppColors.orangeColorDark
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              customText(context),
              const SizedBox(height: 10,),
              getNowBtn()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        right: 0, // Adjust this value according to your requirement
        bottom: 0, // Adjust this value according to your requirement
        child: Image.asset(MediaConstants.menImage, width: width * 0.49,height: height*0.2,),
      ),
    ],
  );

my code output


Try below code:
SizedBox(
        height: 220,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Advanced Salary',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      const Text('For Any Jobs',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              letterSpacing: 2,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 6,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {},
                        child: const Text('Get Now',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            fixedSize: Size(150, 20)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: Image.network(
                'https://i.ibb.co/7Kr3Vc2/Screenshot-2022-02-23-at-6-11-05-PM-removebg-preview.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 210,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )

Result: 

the image height should not be limited to the container
to do that you should put the entire stack widget in a sized box and give it a height slightly bigger than that of the container.
